Are these 3 related questions duplicates? If not, where should I (not) answer?
I was about to answer Is there a way to highlight certain class usage as a warning? but before doing so, I wanted to make sure it had no duplicates.
After searching, I found these 2 pretty related questions : How to generate a warning if a specific enum value is used and Generate warning on specific method call (.net binary class library) but I'm unsure if any would be good duplicate targets for the question I was about to answer (or for each other) given they all mention different symbols (respectively class, enum value and method).
Assuming these questions aren't duplicates, given my answer (assuming minor changes on the example) would also apply to the other 2 questions, where should I (not) answer? Should I try to create a self-answered canonical question and flag these 3 as duplicates of the canonical?

Thinking outside of the box... you could try to Google the problem and see which of the questions pops up.

@Gimby I'm not sure to understand what you mean, do you mean using the result of the google search as the duplicate target of the others?

Given Karl's answer (the only one so far) to go for the self-answered canonical hasn't been positively received, nobody in C# chat room answered and none of the questions I mentionned have been closed as duplicates of each other, I'll use the most status quo (questions-wise) approach and provide a specific yet similar answer to the 3 questions (respectively 1, 2 and 3)

I don't use an IDE, so this is outside of my subject-matter expertise. But it does seem like you've identified multiple separate questions along the lines of "how do I get the IDE to highlight certain use patterns?".
If there are any practical techniques for this that would be specific to a particular "use pattern", then the questions should remain separate. However, that seems unlikely in this case. It isn't readily obvious that these are examples of a broader question, but it should probably be dealt with that way. My vote is for creating (and using as a dupe target) the self-answered canonical that you describe. Consider discussing this in an appropriate chat room (such as the one for C#) first. Ideally, working out the exact scope of the question would be a community effort.

brought it to the c# chat room
